# How to change the Menu Icon in Raspbian

Tags: pi-3

i have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B Version 1.2. I have installed Raspbian OS on it.

I am making a project to a Truck, and i want to remove the Raspberry Pi Menu Icon and put a Mercedes Logo, how do i do it?

**Any awnser will be Appreciated**

Comment: What menu icon exactly?

Comment: @Fabian the main menu; the menu of the aplications, of the run and of the Shutdown

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first, have your Mercedes logo downloaded, then follow these instructions:

1. right-click in a blank space on the taskbar, or on the clock in the upper right corner.
2. click on `Panel Settings`
3. slect the `Panel Applets` tab.
4. select `Menu` in the list, and then click on `Preferences` to the right.
5. in the box that pops up, click `browse`, navigate to your image and choose it, then click `ok`, then `close`.

you should now have a different menu icon!!

**EDIT**:
(Untested) @BotSpot below pointed out that you can just right click on the menu icon to access preferences instead.

Comment: thank you! but i done it another way:
i modified the `raspberrypi-artwork` folder icons


Thank you anyway

Comment: Cool! I was actually trying to find a way to do it that way, but couldn't. Where _is_ the path that contains `raspberrypi-artwork` @IanPauloPerina ?

Comment: The directory is `/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork` @scitronboy , the `launch` is the Menu Icon

Comment: thank you for that! You should answer your own question so other people can see the alternative `/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork` route!

Comment: It is Done ;) @scitronboy

Comment: This is literally _amazing_! I am having fun changing the image  **_multiple times.._** (Pokeball, Windows Icon, etc..)

Comment: **Why not just right-click on the menu button itself --> Menu Settings?** It's so much faster!

Comment: @Botspot it's handy if you need to change it programatically

Comment: It didn;t work for me. I'm running raspbian bullseye

Comment: This didn't work for me too... and I am running bullseye...

Answer (score 5):

i was browsing system files and i discovered the directory of the main logos: `/usr/share/raspberrypi-artwork` **NOTE: You will need admin rights to modify this files**

The `launch` is the Menu Icon.

Thanks [@scitronboy](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/75152/scitronboy) for suggesting me to awnser my own question ;)

**NOTE:** Keep images in their original format and name, you can't replace `example.png` with `example.jpg`

Comment: **NOTE: All of the images have to be in .PNG**

Comment: One of them is formatted in SVG..

Comment: This didn't work for me... I am running bullseye.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way , Remember it's a Linux based system and nothing is hidden.

There is a file named "index.theme" in the usr/share/icons/hicolor

Using the terminal open the file.

Use command: sudo nano /usr/share/icons/hicolor/index.theme

When the file opens edit the 4th line "Hidden=True" change it to False then press ctrl+x , yes, ctrl+m

Hope this helps , worked for me.

Comment: Having a hidden Mercedes logo in Raspbian would be very weird and not very legal. I doubt it's there.

Comment: This DIDN'T work at all. In fact, it took away or hidden the icon from menu button.